# Structure bindings for class data accessed through member functions

Tags: c++, structured-bindings

Stroustrup mentions in his book *A Tour of C++* (section 3.6.3) that it is possible to do structured bindings for a class whose data is accessible through member functions. Here's the example code he gives:

```
complex<double> z = {1,2}
auto [re,im] = z+2
```

Then he says,

> Mapping a `complex<double>` to two local variables, such as `re` and `im` is feasible and efficient,
> but the technique for doing so is beyond the scope of this book.

What is he referring to by "the technique for doing so"?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding#Case_2:_binding_a_tuple-like_type

Answer (score 3):

Check out [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding#Case_2:_binding_a_tuple-like_type).

You specialize `std::tuple_size<T>` and `std::tuple_element<T>` for your type, and provide `get<I>(...)` either in the same namespace (where it can be found by [ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl)) or as a member function.

`get` needs 4 overloads: for `T &`, `const T &`, `T &&`, and `const T &&`, though in some cases you might be able to get away with less overloads.

`tuple_size` and `tuple_element` only need one specialization each. You don't need to manually specialize for `const` and/or `volatile` `T`, since the standard library already defines generic specializations for `const` and/or `volatile` types that forward to the non-qualified specializations.

Example:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

struct A
{
    int unused;
    int x;
    float y;
    std::string z;

    template <std::size_t I>
    friend auto &get(A &a)
    {
        static_assert(I < 3);
        if constexpr (I == 0)
            return a.x;
        else if constexpr (I == 1)
            return a.y;
        else
            return a.z;
    }

    template <std::size_t I>
    friend const auto &get(const A &a)
    {
        return get<I>(const_cast<A &>(a));
    }

    template <std::size_t I>
    friend auto &&get(A &&a)
    {
        return get<I>(static_cast<A &>(a));
    }

    template <std::size_t I>
    friend const auto &&get(const A &&a)
    {
        return get<I>(const_cast<A &&>(a));
    }
};

template <>
struct std::tuple_size<A> : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 3> {};

template <std::size_t I>
struct std::tuple_element<I, A>
{
    static_assert(I < 3);
    using type =
        std::conditional_t<I == 0, int,
        std::conditional_t<I == 1, float,
                                   std::string>>;
};

auto [f, g, h] = A{};
```

Variation 1: `get` defined outside of the class.

```
struct A
{
    int unused;
    int x;
    float y;
    std::string z;
};

template <std::size_t I>
auto &get(A &a)
{
    static_assert(I < 3);
    if constexpr (I == 0)
        return a.x;
    else if constexpr (I == 1)
        return a.y;
    else
        return a.z;
}

template <std::size_t I>
const auto &get(const A &a)
{
    return get<I>(const_cast<A &>(a));
}

template <std::size_t I>
auto &&get(A &&a)
{
    return get<I>(static_cast<A &>(a));
}

template <std::size_t I>
const auto &&get(const A &&a)
{
    return get<I>(const_cast<A &&>(a));
}
```

Variation 2: `get` is a non-static member function.

```
struct A
{
    int unused;
    int x;
    float y;
    std::string z;

    template <std::size_t I>
    auto &get() &
    {
        static_assert(I < 3);
        if constexpr (I == 0)
            return x;
        else if constexpr (I == 1)
            return y;
        else
            return z;
    }

    template <std::size_t I>
    const auto &get() const &
    {
        return const_cast<A *>(this)->get<I>();
    }

    template <std::size_t I>
    auto &&get() &&
    {
        return get<I>();
    }

    template <std::size_t I>
    const auto &&get() const &&
    {
        return get<I>();
    }
};
```